# How do I define a promise flow that is fulfilled on demand?

Tags: javascript, promise

Is there any chance that I can define a promise chain without resolving them until I want to "start" the sequence?

My use case:

```
let a = [
           promiseA1.then(()=>promiseB1),
           promiseA2.then(()=>promiseB2), 
           ..., 
           promiseAn.then(()=>promiseBn)
]

Promise.all(a).then(onSuccess,onError)
```

Comment: Promises are things that are *already running*. It isn't something that you start later. You can, however, define a function that returns a promise, so you'd need to call it to kick off stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Put everything in a function and call that function when you want to start it.

A promise always represents a result, not a startable task.

Comment: the problem is that the array is created dynamically . there is a chance that when ill push the second chain that the promiseA1 would be already resolved/rejected

Comment: @OvidiuMihota That's not a problem. `then` also works on promises that already were fulfilled or rejected.